# Disabling Pylint no member- E1101 error for specific libraries

Tags: pandas, pylint

Is there a way to hide `E1101` errors for objects that are created from a specific library?  Our large repository is littered with `#pylint: disable=E1101` around various objects created by pandas.

For example, Pylint will throw a *no member* error on the following code:

```
import pandas.io.data
import pandas as pd
spy = pandas.io.data.DataReader("SPY", "yahoo")
spy.to_csv("test.csv")
spy = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
close_px = spy.ix["2012":]
```

It will have the following errors:

```
E:  6,11: Instance of 'tuple' has no 'ix' member (no-member)
E:  6,11: Instance of 'TextFileReader' has no 'ix' member (no-member)
```

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you do not wish to globally disable this error check?

Comment: I don't want to globally disable it. I want to disable it for anything created by pandas.

Comment: The discussion around this answer might convince you that you probably can't, but you can tell pylint to ignore errors on individual lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26668602/270001

Comment: Would it be helpful to you to have a hierarchy of config files such that the setting is allowed globally by default, but you have more restrictive configs in folders specific to these modules? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19308989/3182836

Comment: honestly, it wouldn't.  So many modules we use rely on various pandas functionality.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can mark their attributes as dynamically generated using `generated-members` option.

E.g. for pandas:

```
generated-members=pandas.*
```

Comment: Where do you place this line?

Comment: @caliph In the .pylintrc - pylint config file.

Comment: @EdwardHartnett, user3313834: This would only work for members matched by "pandas.*". In the OP, for example, the ix attribute is not accessed on "pandas" but on the object identified as "spy". Something which would work but might be too aggressive, would be to label any member matched precisely by "ix":
`generated-members=ix` under the [TYPECHECK] section of your .pylintrc file.

Comment: This disabled all linting messages for me....until I created a valid .pylintrc file and added `pandas.*` to `generated-members`.

Enter `$ pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc` in the terminal (while in your project folder), then open that file, and add `pandas.*` on the `generated-members=` line.

Comment: Lot's of people saying this doesn't work for them, but it worked like a charm for me. For those that it is not working for, make sure your `.pylintrc` file is actually being read, and that your regex is correct. Thanks for this answer, saves me so much irritation!!

Comment: I'm using pylint 2.3.1 with vscode, and it complains that this option is unrecognized. I simply used `# pylint: disable=no-member` at the top of the python module and that fixes the problem; the alternative is marking each relevant line with this and that gets a bit nope from me.

Answer (score 11):

This failed for me trying to ignore errors in [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), until I tried:

```
generated-members=np.*
```

Since, like most everybody, I do

```
import numpy as np
```

Since generated-members takes a list, one might do:

```
generated-members=numpy.*,np.*
```

Answer (score 6):

*Additional information, on top of [the answer from carabas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961756/disabling-pylint-no-member-e1101-error-for-specific-libraries/35106735#35106735):*

You will find `generated-members` in the `TYPECHECK` section of `.pylintrc`.

Here is the default one:

```
[TYPECHECK]
…
# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E0201 when accessed.
generated-members=REQUEST,acl_users,aq_parent
```

Note that the comment about suppressing E0201 is incomplete.

So you have to update this to:

```
# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E0201 or E1101 when accessed.
generated-members=REQUEST,acl_users,aq_parent,pandas.*
```