# pylint complain if we use pandas class instances

Tags: python, pylint

pylint complain about pandas class instances::

I have db instance that has `data` (a panda Dataframe) as instance.

If I call e.g. iloc or shape on it::

```
cols = db.data.shape
xxx = db.data.iloc[1:4, 0:9]
```

pylint complain about::

```
E: 36,18: Instance of 'TextFileReader' has no 'iloc' member (no-member)
E: 92,30: Instance of 'TextFileReader' has no 'shape' member (no-member)
E: 92,30: Instance of 'tuple' has no 'shape' member (no-member)
```

I've try [How do I get PyLint to recognize numpy members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553551/how-do-i-get-pylint-to-recognize-numpy-members) and [Disabling Pylint no member- E1101 error for specific libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961756/disabling-pylint-no-member-e1101-error-for-specific-libraries/35106735) with no success.

Comment: It seems db.data is a TextFileReader instance instead of DataFrame. This happens under some condition like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844485/why-the-object-which-i-read-a-csv-file-using-pandas-from-is-textfilereader-obj, have you checked it?

Comment: As @YCFlame pointed out, pylint thinks the type is TextFileReader. One can only guess as to why, without incuding your code of what db.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution to getting TextFileReader to DataFrame https://stackoverflow.com/a/70212439/761829

Comment: I does not look reasonable to change the code jute to workaround pylint Pbs, did you ?

Comment: Maybe you should just suppress errors with adding comment `# pylint: disable=no-member`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4577) in `pylint` that has been marked high priority as of March 14th 2022.

The issue stems from the underlying AST engine that `pylint` uses that has a limit to the number of inferences it can make at runtime as a bid to improve performance.

For posteriority in case the link above ever dies, the workaround is as follows:

```sh
pylint some_file_to_lint.py --init-hook "import astroid; astroid.context.InferenceContext.max_inferred = 500"
```

Or in `.pylintrc`:

```py
[MASTER]

init-hook = "import astroid; astroid.context.InferenceContext.max_inferred = 500"
```